# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString is not working

Tags: ios

I want to Change the time format to be displayed from 1 to 1,00

**Code:**

```
 lblLoggedHoursValue.text = [lblLoggedHoursValue.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];
```

Comment: You don't have "." in your string "1" then how can you replace & get result as 1,00. For this you have to just add extra text from your end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i converting your value in float and then after replace.

```
lblLoggedHoursValue.text = @"1";
lblLoggedHoursValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[lblLoggedHoursValue.text floatValue]];

NSLog(@"%@",lblLoggedHoursValue.text); //Output : 1.00
```

Now replace lblLoggedHoursValue.text (.) to (,)

```
lblLoggedHoursValue.text = [lblLoggedHoursValue.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@","];

NSLog(@"%@",lblLoggedHoursValue.text); //Output : 1,00
```